# AngularJS: filter array of object by property name

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, object, filter

I have an array:

```
$scope.default = [
    {name:'bigid',desc:'Incrementing ID using <code>BIGINT</code>'},
    {name:'timestamps',desc:'Add <code>TIMESTAMP</code> columns'},
    {name:'ntimestamps',desc:'Allow <code>TIMESTAMP</code> null'},
    {name:'softdelete',desc:'Support <code>SOFTDELETE<code>'},
    {name:'rem_token',desc:'Adds <code>remember_token</code>'}
];
```

But, I wanna filter that I have result:

```
[
    {name:'bigid'},
    {name:'timestamps'},
    {name:'ntimestamps'},
    {name:'softdelete'},
    {name:'rem_token'}
];
```

Help me, please. Should I can do this only with AngularJS Filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```
$scope.default = [
    {name:'bigid',desc:'Incrementing ID using <code>BIGINT</code>'},
    {name:'timestamps',desc:'Add <code>TIMESTAMP</code> columns'},
    {name:'ntimestamps',desc:'Allow <code>TIMESTAMP</code> null'},
    {name:'softdelete',desc:'Support <code>SOFTDELETE<code>'},
    {name:'rem_token',desc:'Adds <code>remember_token</code>'}
];

$scope.default = $scope.default.map(function (el) {
    return {name: el.name};
});
```